# Definition of modulo division

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could anyone tell me why
$3/7\equiv 9 \mod12$? How is this operation defined and why sometimes modulo division is impossible, like in the case of $3/4 \mod 12$?
See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=X8aqCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more details, I'm refering to page 95.

I can't grasp why $3/7\equiv 9 \mod12$. I divide $3$ by $7$, what I get is $3 = 0 \times 7 + 3$, the remainder is $3$. Now how is it equal to $9$ mod $12$?

Comment: $1/7$ modulo $12$ is an integer $k \bmod 12$ with $7k\equiv 1 \bmod 12$. This is $k=7$. Note that now $3\cdot 7\equiv 9\bmod 12$.

Comment: The page 95 in the link doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:
$$\frac{3}{7} = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{7} = 3 \cdot 7^{-1}.$$

So then
\begin{align}
  \frac{3}{7} \mod 12 &= (3 \cdot 7^{-1}) \mod 12\\
            &= (3 \mod 12) \cdot (7^{-1} \mod 12).
\end{align}

$3 \mod 12$ is just 3.  What's $7^{-1} \mod 12$?  In other words, find $x$ so that $7x \equiv 1 \mod 12$.  Then multiply this $x$ by 3 and evaluate modulo 12 again.

Comment: Umm... how to find $x$? $1 \mod 12$ is $1$, so I want $x$ such that dividing $7x$ by $12$ gives $1$ as the remainder. Is there any procedure I can use to find $x$?

Comment: In simple cases like this just try every $x$ from $1$ to $11$.

Comment: I would instead think of it as "I want $x$ such that multiplying 7 by $x$ gives me one more than a multiple of 12."  And I'd find that $x$ by doing exactly what N74 said.